# How to uninstall old version of nodejs on Amzon EC2 Instance - Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-ec2, mongoose

I would like to use mongodb and nodejs(latest version) on my Amazon EC2 Ubuntu instance. But, when I created my instance I had nodejs_v0.4.9 installed.

Now I would like to upgrade the version of nodejs so that I can use mongoose module to connect to mongodb. Can someone help me?

Comment: I've followed the instructions given in http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/09/01/deploying-node-js-on-amazon-ec2/ and was able to upgrade the version of nodejs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm always prefer to use the package management system. You can use [packages](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/chris_lea_nodejs/oneiric/main/base/nodejs) from launchpad for 11.10. The complete process should be like this:

```
sudo apt-get purge nodejs npm
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs npm
```

Most recent node packages but only for 12.04 & 12.10 located [here](https://launchpad.net/~richarvey/+archive/nodejs).

Comment: Thanks Atma!!! I guess, your solution works too. But I've already updated my nodejs as mentioned in my post's comment.

Answer (score 0):

if you have NPM installed do the following:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```